# Where is SetOaNoCache defined?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, disable-caching

Attempting to **disable** BSTR caching:

```
SetOaNoCache();
```

VC++ compiler **build output**:

- `'SetOaNoCache': identifier not found`

**Don't** want to use:

- OANOCACHE=1

**Question:**

- Where is [SetOaNoCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644360.aspx) **defined** - header file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not defined in a header file, it is in OLEAUT32.dll. You can call it like this:

```
typedef int (*SETOANOCACHE)(void);
```

void DisableBSTRCache()
{
    HINSTANCE hLib = LoadLibrary("OLEAUT32.DLL");
    if (hLib != NULL)
    {
        SETOANOCACHE SetOaNoCache = (SETOANOCACHE)GetProcAddress(hLib, "SetOaNoCache");
        if (SetOaNoCache != NULL)
            SetOaNoCache();
        FreeLibrary(hLib);
    }
}

Comment: +1: @sikx - thanks dude! I'll try it out :). Where can I find out more about this? How did you know it was in OLEAUT32.dll?

Comment: 2 minutes with google: http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/VC/microsoft.public.vc.atl/2005-03/0184.html

Comment: Should be declared as "void __cdecl SetOaNoCache(void)". See MSDN article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644360(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 3):

It's not. From the Win32 API library shipped with C++ Builder:

```
Requirements

Windows XP: Requires Windows XP Service Pack 2 or later.

Windows 95/98: Not supported.

Header: Not supplied. Declare prototype as shown.

Library: Use oleaut32.lib.
```

The prototype as shown:

```
inline void TurnOffCache ()
{
// Function prototype.
extern "C" SetOaNoCache(); 
// Turn off BSTR caching.
SetOaNoCache();
}
```