# COM memory management

Tags: memory-management, com

I have some questions regarding COM memory management:

1. I have a COM method:

   STDMETHODIMP CWhitelistPolicy::GetWebsitesStrings(SAFEARRAY** result)

result = SAFEARRAY(BSTR). If I receive another  SAFEARRAY(BSTR) from another interface method(in order to set *result) do I have to make copies of the strings received in order to pass them to *result and outside client? Or considering I will not use the strings for myself I can just pass them to the client (and passing out the ownership)?

2.

```
STDMETHODIMP CWhitelistPolicy::SetWebsitesStrings(SAFEARRAY* input)
```

Here I receive a BSTR array as input. Again my method is responsible for the memory allocated in input?

3.

```
STDMETHOD(SetUsers)(SAFEARRAY* input);
```

Here I call a method on another interface (SetUsers) and I allocate memory for the input SAFEARRAY. After I call SetUsers I can dispose of the SAFEARRAY? Memory is always copied when marshaling takes place isn't it? (in my case SetUsers method is called on an interface that is hosted as a COM DLL inside my process)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I think about it to answer questions like this is to think about a COM call that crosses machines.  Then it's obvious for an [out] param; I the caller own and have to free the memory because the remote marshaling layer can't do it.  For [in] parameters, it's obvious the marshaling layer must copy my data and again the remote marshaling layer can't free what I passed in.

A core tenet in COM is location neutrality, the rules when calling in the same apartment are the rules when using DCOM across machines.

1. You're responsible to free - you don't pass ownership when you call the next fnc because it could be remote and getting a copy, not your original data.
2. No - as the callee, you don't have to free it.  If it's intra-apartment, it's the memory the caller provided and the caller has to free it.  If it's a remote call, the server stub allocates it and will free it when the method returns.
3. Yes, you free it - no, it's not always copied (it might be), which is why the answer to 2 is no.  If it's copied, there's a stub that allocated and the stub will free it.

Note my answers to your questions didn't cover the case of [in,out] parameters - see the so question [Who owns returned BSTR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872794/who-owns-returned-bstr/872802#872802) for some more details on this case.

[Com allocation rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378697%28VS.85%29.aspx) are complicated but rational. Get the book "essential com" by Don Box if you want to understand/see examples of all the cases.  Still you're going to make mistakes so you should have a strategy for detecting them. I use gflags (part of [Windbg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff561300%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) and its heap checking flags to catch when a double free occurs (a debug message is displayed and execution halted at the call with an INT 3).  Vstudio's debugger used to turn them on for you when it launched the executable (it likely still does) but you can force them on with gflags under the image options tab.

You should also know how to use [UMDH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff558947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (also part of windbg) to detect leaks.  [DebugDiag](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=24370) is the newer tool for this and seems easier to use, but sadly, you can only have the 32 bit or 64 bit version installed, but not both.

The problem then are BSTRs, which are cached, make detecting double frees and leaks tricky because interacting with the heap is delayed.  You can shut off the ole string cache by setting the environment variable  [OANOCACHE](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=http://support.microsoft.com:80/support/kb/articles/q139/0/71.asp&NoWebContent=1) to 1 or calling the function [SetOaNoCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The function's not defined in a header file so see this SO question [Where is SetOaNoCache defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553846/where-is-setoanocache-defined).  Note the accepted answer shows the hard way to call it through GetProcAddress().  The answer below the accepted one shows all you need is an extern "C" as it's in the oleaut32 export lib.  Finally, see [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2004/09/28/235304.aspx) Larry Osterman blog post for a more detailed description of the difficulties caused by the cache when hunting leaks.

Comment: so to be a little more clear for me :-) - all memory that I receive as input (from the perspective of the caller) is not in my ownership - that is the job of the server stub. All memory that I pass as output(from the perspective of the caller) is my ownership - that is after the method call I have to release the passed memory otherwise it will leak.

Comment: In the cases you gave, yes. For [in,out] no in the case you're modifying the data that has come in.  The stub just frees what's returned before marshaling back the caller so if you want to modify what's come in, you had to free it.  I updated the answer with other advice about how to figure out when you have it wrong.